# WinUI3 & Unoplatform: Drawing brush on image/video surface while playing and save it directly on original file

Tags: computer-vision, winui-3

Hello I am building an image/video editing application (runs on window 11) using Unoplatform.
(Unoplatform internally use WinUI3)

What i want to do is

- App can load image/video frame on canvas
- Use brush effect on frame surface like drawing pad feature
- During playing video, user can add effect on every frame and modified frame saved right away on original file.
- During playing video, do computer vision processing to recognize object and add mark on frame
- Audio must playable

[image]

So my question is,

1. How can I add an effect to only a specific frame in the original video and save it using Unoplatform(or WinUI3) API?
2. Is it possible to play video on canvas view and get frame by frame from MediaPlayer?

Comment: It seems you want [MediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.mediaplayer?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) which *Provides access to media playback functionality such as play, pause, fast-forward, rewind, and volume*.

Comment: Could you teach me how to render MediaPlayer's frame output to Canvas control?

Comment: [Canvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas?view=winrt-22621) *Defines an area within which you can explicitly position child objects, using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area* and *In many cases, a Canvas is used solely as a container for other objects and does not have any visible properties*. You can put a MediaPlayerElement to a Canvas and [The ProcessFrame method is where your effect modifies the image data of the video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects#processframe-method).